# what is the pregmatch to retrieve these values using javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the reg expression for this using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355422/what-is-the-reg-expression-for-this-using-javascript)

How to retrieve the value 100003119917070 and XgXELcliKMkSCcS from below document using preg match

```
<script>
window.Env = window.Env || {};
(function(v) { 
  for (var k in v) { window.Env[k] = v[k]; } 
})({
  "user": "100003119917070", 
  "locale": "en_US", 
  "method": "GET", 
  "ps_limit": 5, 
  "ps_ratio": 4, 
  "svn_rev": 479734, 
  "static_base": "https:\/\/s-static.ak.facebook.com\/", 
  "www_base": "http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/", 
  "rep_lag": 2, 
  "post_form_id": "6cea66d4118fac268304a538a5004ed7", 
  "fb_dtsg": "AQAcBeoe", 
  "ajaxpipe_token": "AXgXELcliKMkSCcS", 
  "lhsh": "8AQGGa7eN", 
  "tracking_domain": "https:\/\/pixel.facebook.com",
  "retry_ajax_on_network_error": "1", 
  "ajaxpipe_enabled": "1"
 });
 </script>
 <script>
 CavalryLogger=false;
 window._incorporate_fragment = true;
 window._script_path = "\/home.php";
 window._EagleEyeSeed="Se1E";
 </script>
```

Comment: Somebody should ban that guy...

Comment: @user1077264 no, it's no different.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge javascript has no pregmatch.

Comment: Pregmatch? I'm guessing that's a service to help match would-be parents with surrogate mothers?

Comment: @user1077264 You've been given tonns of solutions in your previous topics. If you don't like them - that means your are formulating your question wrong. Try explaining in detail: 1. What do you need to do. 2. What have you tried doing. 3. At which step are you stuck. `Nobody here is willing to do all your job for you for free.`

Comment: We can't help you because we can't understand what you are asking. You talk about retrieving values "from below document" and then show a script block - does that mean you want to treat the whole block as a big string (i.e., as a document) to be processed by another script? Did you write that script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By preg match do you mean regex match/test? Is 'preg' not either depreciated or from PHP? and assuming you tagged the question JavaScript, and not PHP you're wanting the JavaScript solution?

Either way I would do the following:

```
var val1regex = /"user":\s?"([0-9]+)/;
var val2regex = /"ajaxpipe_token":\s?"([\d\w]+)/;

var val1 = SOURCE.match(val1regex);
var val2 = SOURCE.match(val2regex);
```

Where `SOURCE` is a string containing the data you asked to check against.

I'd recommend using something like [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com) in the future and actually learn some regex before just expecting other people to do the work for you. By all means ask for help, but well dont abuse peoples willingness to help.

See: [Working with your example in regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/?flags=&regex=%22ajaxpipe_token%22%3a%5Cs?%22%28%5B%5Cd%5Cw%5D%2b%29&input=%3Cscript%3E%0Awindow.Env%20=%20window.Env%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D;%0A%28function%28v%29%20%7B%20%0A%20%20for%20%28var%20k%20in%20v%29%20%7B%20window.Env%5Bk%5D%20=%20v%5Bk%5D;%20%7D%20%0A%7D%29%28%7B%0A%20%20%22user%22%3a%20%22100003119917070%22,%20%0A%20%20%22locale%22%3a%20%22en_US%22,%20%0A%20%20%22method%22%3a%20%22GET%22,%20%0A%20%20%22ps_limit%22%3a%205,%20%0A%20%20%22ps_ratio%22%3a%204,%20%0A%20%20%22svn_rev%22%3a%20479734,%20%0A%20%20%22static_base%22%3a%20%22https%3a%5C/%5C/s-static.ak.facebook.com%5C/%22,%20%0A%20%20%22www_base%22%3a%20%22http%3a%5C/%5C/www.facebook.com%5C/%22,%20%0A%20%20%22rep_lag%22%3a%202,%20%0A%20%20%22post_form_id%22%3a%20%226cea66d4118fac268304a538a5004ed7%22,%20%0A%20%20%22fb_dtsg%22%3a%20%22AQAcBeoe%22,%20%0A%20%20%22ajaxpipe_token%22%3a%20%22AXgXELcliKMkSCcS%22,%20%0A%20%20%22lhsh%22%3a%20%228AQGGa7eN%22,%20%0A%20%20%22tracking_domain%22%3a%20%22https%3a%5C/%5C/pixel.facebook.com%22,%0A%20%20%22retry_ajax_on_network_error%22%3a%20%221%22,%20%0A%20%20%22ajaxpipe_enabled%22%3a%20%221%22%0A%20%7D%29;%0A%20%3C/script%3E%0A%20%3Cscript%3E%0A%20CavalryLogger=false;%0A%20window._incorporate_fragment%20=%20true;%0A%20window._script_path%20=%20%22%5C/home.php%22;%0A%20window._EagleEyeSeed=%22Se1E%22;%0A%20%3C/script%3E%0A)