# what is the preg match to extract this values using js

Tags: javascript

How to retrieve the value `100003119917070` and `XgXELcliKMkSCcS` from below document using preg match:

```
<script>
window.Env = window.Env || {};
(function(v) { 
  for (var k in v) { window.Env[k] = v[k]; } 
})({
  "user": "100003119917070", 
  "locale": "en_US", 
  "method": "GET", 
  "ps_limit": 5, 
  "ps_ratio": 4, 
  "svn_rev": 479734, 
  "static_base": "https:\/\/s-static.ak.facebook.com\/", 
  "www_base": "http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/", 
  "rep_lag": 2, 
  "post_form_id": "6cea66d4118fac268304a538a5004ed7", 
  "fb_dtsg": "AQAcBeoe", 
  "ajaxpipe_token": "AXgXELcliKMkSCcS", 
  "lhsh": "8AQGGa7eN", 
  "tracking_domain": "https:\/\/pixel.facebook.com",
  "retry_ajax_on_network_error": "1", 
  "ajaxpipe_enabled": "1"
 });
 </script>
 <script>
 CavalryLogger=false;
 window._incorporate_fragment = true;
 window._script_path = "\/home.php";
 window._EagleEyeSeed="Se1E";
 </script>
```

Comment: i don't get you, what you want anyway?

Comment: i want to extract this value  
  "ajaxpipe_token": "AXgXELcliKMkSCcS",

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the pregmatch to retrieve these values using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355648/what-is-the-pregmatch-to-retrieve-these-values-using-javascript)

Comment: If you're capable of writing the code above you're capable of getting the values you want from it, so can we assume you didn't write it and this is some kind of homework, or...? Are you saying you want to add some additional code to the above to get the values associated with "user" and "ajaxpipe_token" - what do you want to do with the values? You don't need to store them in variables because they're already directly accessible as per missingno's answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just access `window.Env.user` and `window.env.ajax_token`?

Comment: how to access that??i am noob please help me sir

Comment: They are global variables with that name

Comment: can u explain little bit deatail sir..please i will be vey thankfull to you

Comment: no i cant teach you basic concepts like that. you have to learn yourself

Comment: Topic? You need a beginning JavaScript tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You've put(copy) the object into the window.Env, so you can run this code:

`console.log(window.Env.user, window.Env.ajaxpipe_token)`

and it will print values which you want on console.

Also, you can use `window.Env['user']` to reference the value `100003119917070`.

if use preg,

```
var preg_user= /"user":\s?"([0-9]+)/;
var preg_token = /"ajaxpipe_token":\s?"([\d\w]+)/;
```

and you can get value by:

```
var user = str.match(preg_user);
var token = str.match(preg_token);
```

May this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

In the specific example given ajaxpipe_token does not contain values other than text and numbers, but, if your value can contain other values (like it can in facebook), change your match group to look for non-quotes, then terminate with the quotes.   This is the full code for extracting the values from the document.

```
scriptxpath ='//script[contains(.,"ajaxpipe_token")]';
scriptrslt = document.evaluate(scriptxpath,document,null,XPathResult.ANY_TYPE,null);
scriptobj = scriptrslt.iterateNext()
scriptiHTML = script.innerHTML;

user_search = scriptiHTML.match(/"user":\s?"([0-9]+)"/);
ajaxpipe_token_search = script_iHTML.match(/"ajaxpipe_token":\s?"([^"]+)"/)

user = user_search[1];
ajaxpipe_token = ajaxpipe_token_search[1];
```